# Task scheduling to minimize waiting time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I am completely stuck on a task scheduling problem.

Here is the requirement:
Implement a scheduling algorithm that adds jobs to the regular queue and pushes them through in such a way that the average wait time for all jobs in the queue is minimized. A new job isn't pushed through unless it minimizes the average waiting time.
Assume that your program starts working at 0 seconds. A request for the ith job came at requestTimei, and let's assume that it takes jobProcessi seconds to process it.

```
def jobScheduling(requestTime, jobProcess, timeFromStart):

    requestTimeAndDuration={}
    for i in range(len(requestTime)):
        job=[]
        job.append(requestTime[i])
        job.append(jobProcess[i])
        requestTimeAndDuration[i]=job

    taskProcessed=[]
    previousEndTime=0
    while (requestTimeAndDuration):
        endTimes={}
        for k,v in requestTimeAndDuration.items():
            if(len(taskProcessed)==0):
                previousEndTime=0
            else:
                previousEndTime=taskProcessed[-1][1]
            #print previousEndTime
            if(v[0]<=previousEndTime):
                endTimes[k]= previousEndTime+v[1]
            else:
                endTimes[k]= v[0]+v[1]

        endTimesSorted = sorted(endTimes.items(), key=lambda endTimes: endTimes[1])
        nextJobId = endTimesSorted[0][0]
        nextJobEndTime = endTimesSorted[0][1]
        nextJob=[]
        nextJob.append(nextJobId)
        previousEndTime=0
        if(len(taskProcessed)>0):
            previousEndTime=taskProcessed[-1][1]
        nextJobStarTime = nextJobEndTime-jobProcess[nextJobId]
        nextJob.append(nextJobEndTime)
        nextJob.append(nextJobStarTime)
        taskProcessed.append(nextJob)
        del requestTimeAndDuration[nextJobId]
print taskProcessed
```

My algorithm tries to sort the tasks by its end time, which is computed from previousEndTime + currentJobProcess
requestTime = [0, 5, 8, 11], jobProcess = [9, 4, 2, 1]

- iteration 1:

  task = [[0,9],[5,4],[8,2][11,1]] 
  PreviousEndTime=0 //since we started, there were no previous tasks 0+9=9, 5+4=9, 8+2=10, 11+1=12
  endTime = {0:9, 1:9, 2:11, 3:12} //take task 0 and remove it from tasks
- iteration 2:

  task = [[5,4],[8,2][11,1]]
  PreviousEndTime=9 9+4=13,  9+2=11, 11+1=12 
  endTime = {1:13,2:11,3:12}  //remove task 2
- iteration 3:

  task = [[5,4],[11,1]]
  previousEndTime=11
  11+4=15, 11+1=12
  endTime = {1:13,3:12}  //remove task 3
- iteration 4:

  task = [[5,4],[11,1]]
  previousEndTime=12
  12+4=15
  endTime = {1:16}  //remove task 1

**Final Result printed is [0,2,3,1]**

My problem is that, my algorithm works for some cases, but not the complicated ones. 
requestTime: [4, 6, 8, 8, 15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 25]
jobProcess: [30, 25, 14, 16, 26, 10, 11, 11, 14, 8]

The answer is [9, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 3, 1, 4]
But my algoritm produces [5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 3, 1, 4, 0]

So does anyone know how to do this problem? I'm afraid my algorithm may be fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Your algorithm's solution and the correct solution in the final example do not include the same integers. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a really neat solution like sorting by end time, but if there is such a solution, you should be able to get the same answer by sorting the tasks using as a comparator a function that works out which task should be scheduled first if those are the only two tasks to be considered.